# Hash Mismatch for Wordpress jquery 1.12.4

Tags: jquery, wordpress, subresource-integrity

I am using latest (4.9.8) WordPress and currently working on adding integrity attribute to `<script>` tags. The version of `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` is `1.12.4`. The SRI (hash) for this is

`sha256-/EjR2A7OcaeaezmHf0EE1J09psNmXPbcIDAA+330RH4=`.

Version `1.12.4` on [jquery site](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) and [Cloudflare CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/1.12.4) has SRI

`sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=`

The code looks minified, but the SRI does not match minified version either. SRI attributes on Cloudflare and jquery sites match for minified versions too.

- Would anyone know why the difference?
- Is it common for WordPress developers to customise jquery (standard) libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js used by Wordpress is a copy of https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js that’s been modified to add `jQuery.noConflict()`, to put it in “no conflict” mode https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/.

I guess Wordpress does that to prevent any conflict in the case where, in your Wordpress site, you might load some other library that uses `$` as a function or variable name.

So, if you want to use that `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` file with subresource integrity, you need to use a different hash than the upstream version — because the contents are different.

---

#### More details

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js<sup>1</sup> diffed against https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js shows this:

```
--- jquery-1.12.4.min.js    2018-10-30 08:44:12.545350081 +0900
+++ jquery.js   2018-10-30 08:38:48.978809390 +0900
@@ -3,3 +3,4 @@
 }return c}function Q(a){var b;for(b in a)if(("data"!==b||!n.isEmptyObject...
 marginLeft:0},function(){return a.getBoundingClientRect().left}):0))+"px"...
 padding:"inner"+a,content:b,"":"outer"+a},function(c,d){n.fn[d]=function...
+jQuery.noConflict();
\ No newline at end of file
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/922f83a69f47c68d9f7adac6520d1de04075d8be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js, to be exact.</sub>

So, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js adds a `jQuery.noConflict();` line and drops the newline from the end of the file.

If you remove that `jQuery.noConflict();` line and add a newline to the end of that  file, then you’ll end up with contents identical to the upstream https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js. And if you generate a hash for that modified file, you get this:

```
$ shasum -b -a 256 jquery-wordpress-modified.js \
    | awk '{ print $1 }' | xxd -r -p | base64

ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=
```

…or…

```
$ cat jquery-wordpress-modified.js \
    | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64 -A

ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=
```

…which matches the hash shown for https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js at the jQuery site:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

> The version of `/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js` is `1.12.4`. The SRI (hash) for this is
>
> ```
> sha256-/EjR2A7OcaeaezmHf0EE1J09psNmXPbcIDAA+330RH4=
> ```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js (which currently shows v1.12.4), when I check it, doesn’t have that hash above; instead it has this:

```
$ curl -s -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/922f83a69f47c68d9f7adac6520d1de04075d8be/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js \
    && cat jquery.js | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64 -A

+gVfL3xbc127txlU9DSu15klvAD/L/vD7PxKeQaJpyM=
```

See also the [Tools for generating SRI hashes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity#Tools_for_generating_SRI_hashes) section of [the MDN article on Subresource Integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity).